# angular - input for a custom MatDialogConfig file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, I have a custom **MaterialDialogConfig** file for all my **[material dialogs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)** which looks like this:

```
import { MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material";

export class MaterialDialogConfig extends MatDialogConfig {
    constructor(data: any = {}, width: string = "720px") {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.width = width;
        this.hasBackdrop = true;
        this.disableClose = true;
        this.closeOnNavigation = true;
    }
}
```

And a dialog component of mine looks like this:

```
constructor(
    private service: AppService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DIALOGCOMPONENT>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) {}

ngOnInit() {}
```

How can I make the **width** property into an input for all separate dialog component instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a quick fix. Just export the variables as constants:

```
import { MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material";

export class MaterialDialogConfig extends MatDialogConfig {
    constructor(data: any = {}, width: string = "720px") {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.width = width;
        this.hasBackdrop = true;
        this.disableClose = true;
        this.closeOnNavigation = true;
    }
}

export const DIALOG_SMALL: string = "480px";
export const DIALOG_MID: string = "720px";
export const DIALOG_BIG: string = "1200px";
```